# Using Java's File class and how to gain correct access permissions to create files

Tags: java

bellow is the code of a house cleaning function i have written, the function  is supposed to check for a files existance, if it is not there it then creates the file and adds some data to it.
However when i check that i have read and write permisions using the `file.canRead()` and `file.canWrite()` these both return false when checked however the program should have access to the file path where specified.

```
public void HouseCleaning()
{
    //inform the user that the file is not available 
    System.out.println("According the the checks we have run, the current system you are on we do not have the required files set up");
    System.out.println("...");
    //create info.txt
    try
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\GameCounter\\info.txt");
        System.out.println(file.canRead());
        System.out.println(file.canWrite());
        if(file.canRead() && file.canWrite())
        {

            //then we can create the file
            System.out.println("we can do this");
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                //file does not exist
                if(file.createNewFile())
                {
                    //file has been created
                    System.out.println("File has been successfully created!");
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\GameCounter\\info.txt", "UTF-8");
                    writer.println("Info File:");
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    //file has not been created!
                    System.out.println("for some reason the file cannot be created!");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //file must already exist? so check for other required ones!
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("we require extre permissions!");
        }





    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //error has been thrown
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}
```

So my question is firstly is that theoretically if the code bellow is correct then it is permissions on the hard disk itself then? if the code is not correct please do correct me. 
Many Thanks for any help regarding this.

Comment: Do these files exist? I dont think so and that is why it returns false.

Comment: Why not simply write and react on the Exception you get if this fails ? I would not check this before accessing the file

Comment: Exactly. Save yourself a dozen lines of wasteful code that the operating system has to execute anyway. There is nothing to be gained by this. Even the `createNewFile()` call is pointless. You're adding timing-window vulnerabilities, repeating work, wasting space and time, and accomplishing exactly nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change your program and use the advantages Javas Exception Handling has to offer.

```
private final static String COUNTER = "C:\\GameCounter\\info.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File(COUNTER);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(COUNTER, "UTF-8");
                writer.println("Info File:");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /// ... more to come
    }
```

This is a lot shorter and you have to take care of the exceptions anyway. If the file can not be written to (In my test I simply created it and assigned the readonly attribute) you will receive an according exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\GameCounter\info.txt (Access denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:192)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:232)
    at xyz.main(xyz.java:12)
```

In my example I only dump the exception to the screen. In a real life scenario you need to react on the exception and perhaps re-throw a exception you defined on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The methods `canRead` and `canWrite` return `false` if the file does not exist.

Quote from the documentation (canRead):

> Returns:
>       true if and only if the file specified by this abstract pathname exists and can be read by the application; false otherwise

and (canWrite):

> Returns:
>       true if and only if the file system actually contains a file denoted by this abstract pathname and the application is allowed to write to the file; false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `file.canRead() file.canWrite()` return false are most likely because you have not created the files.

> Java Doc 
>   public boolean canRead() Tests whether the application can
>   read the file denoted by this abstract pathname.

The method calls return true when you create the files first.
Remember, File is a representation of a system file, simply creating an instance of the File object will not create a file